# read a list of urls and read divs

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to read the data of some divs in a list of urls, but i dont find the correct way, actually i only get a white page, but if do a print_r on the commented code (the $aElements) i can see the url loaded correctly, so i think the error is on the foreach, but i can't fix it, i need the link inside the div with the id=city

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
set_time_limit (2000);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "buss";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT url FROM business";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html = file_get_html($row["url"]);
    $aElements = $html->find('div[id=city]', 0)->find('a');
    $localList = array();
// here if i do a print_r i get the html of each url listed and is fine (of $aElements)
    foreach($aElements as $element) {
        if(substr($element->href, 0, 1) == '/') {
            $ownerName = trim(str_replace('Punto de', '', $element->plaintext));
            $localList[$artistName] =   $element->href;


            $file = fopen("newfile.txt", "a");
            fwrite($file, $localList[$ownerName] =  $element->href . PHP_EOL);
            fclose($file);
        }

     }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: At what point in the code are you trying to echo the data onto the page?

Comment: hi, i leave the comment on the line 20

// here if i do a print_r i get the html of each url listed and is fine (of $aElements) and i dont need the data on the page, i only want save the urls on the .txt file

Comment: Yes... I know... but that is not what I'm asking. You're trying to output the data to the page or are you trying to write it to a file?

Comment: yes, to the file: newfile.txt